# django: form save fails due to validation - but shouldn't is_valid() catch this?

Tags: python, django

I am taking over someone else's code, I am not a django expert but have had some fair share.

We have a page with two forms, FirstForm and SecondForm.

This is the code saving the form:

```
if first_form.is_valid() and second_form.is_valid():
    new_instance = first_form.save()
    second_instance = second_form.save(commit=False)
    second_instance.save()
```

Now, what happens is that the last line, second_instance.save(), fails because one of the elements breaks the model requirements:

```
ValueError: Field value longer than max allowed: 90 > 50
```

But what I fail to understand: shouldn't the `second_form.is_valid()` call actually already catch this situation and prevent `save()` to fail??? 
Does the SecondForm need validation code as well?

Here's part of the definition of the SecondModel, with the property affected:

```
class SecondModel(models.Model):
 address_line_1 = EncryptedCharField(null=True,
                                     blank=True,
                                     max_length=100,
                                     cipher=settings.ENCRYPTION_CIPHER,
                                     block_type=settings.ENCRYPTION_BLOCK_TYPE)
```

Here's the form:

```
class SecondForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SecondForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name in self.fields:
            field = self.fields.get(field_name)
            if field:
                if type(field.widget) in (forms.TextInput,):
                    field.widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': field.label})
                if type(field.widget) in (forms.Textarea,):
                    field.widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': field.label})
                if type(field.widget) in (forms.PasswordInput,):
                    field.widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': field.label})

    class Meta:
        model = SecondModel
        exclude = ('user', 'lat', 'lon')
```

Comment: Where is EncryptedCharField from? Seems likely that the encryption is making the string longer, so the number of chars entered in the field is smaller than the number saved to the db.

Comment: @DanielRoseman that seems to be a django field: `from django_fields.fields import (
       EncryptedFloatField,
       EncryptedCharField,
       EncryptedEmailField,
)`

Comment: No, `django_fields` is not part of Django itself, it's a module in your project or a third-party library. Django's fields are in `django.db.models`.

Comment: This is an open issue for `django_fields`, check this out https://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-fields/issues/17